# Unable to find a specification for OpenSSL

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm trying to make a pod using OpenSSL , But I'm getting the attached error. I'm using the latest beta version -> 1.3.0.beta.2 . When I was on 1.2.1 I was getting the duplicate file name error, which was resolved after updating to latest version. I've tried using --sources but its giving me the same error . I'm using this terminal command for pod creation -> pod lib lint ColorsG.podspec --sources='https://github.com/FredericJacobs/OpenSSL-Pod' --verbose , If the sources has wrong link can anybody point me to the right one because this is the one I found.

This is my subspec in podspec file

```
s.subspec 'InAppPurchase' do |inApp|

inApp.source_files = 'ColorsG/InApp/.{h,m}'

inApp.dependency 'OpenSSL', '1.0.210'

inApp.ios.vendored_library = 'Pods/OpenSSL-Classic/lib-ios/.a'

inApp.vendored_libraries = 'libssl.a', 'libcrypto.a'

end
```

[This is the issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiMMd.png)